# How do I ignore a specific error in Azure CI

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, playwright, teardown

I'm running Playwright tests in an Azure pipeline and teardown likes to randomly fail. I'm not sure what's causing the failure, or how to fix it. My idea was that I would just ignore the pipeline failure, though. The teardown is more of a cleanup, so I don't really care if it runs. Not to mention that it runs 3 time for each pipeline run because I'm running 3 projects. I have no clue how I would ignore that specific error, though. If one of the tests fail, then I need the pipeline to fail because I publish trace files on fail. Is there even a way to do this? I've found a couple of different posts, but all of the ones I found just go with ignoring everything that fails, rather than a specific error. I'd like to do this through the YAML file if possible, as well.

Comment: Use `set +e` then `set -e` around the problematic line?

Comment: @Paolo it's a single command to run Playwright, so this isn't what I would need...